# What to use instead of Function and Object types in Flow

Tags: javascript, flowtype

The Flow documentation advises to use `Function` and `Object` types sparingly. If that's the case, what am I supposed to use? Here are a couple scenarios:

```
export function executeFunction(someFunc) {
  someFunc.call(this, 'whatever');
}

export function processThing(someObj) {
  // ...
}
```

What is the correct way to annotate these? (note: `someObj` could be any object.. and it could have dozens of methods and properties, and I don't want to have to type those all out in the annotation)

Answer (score 1):

Well, for one, since you're not using the output of `processThing`, I assume it returns nothing, so you could add an annotation for that:

```
export function processThing(someObj): void {
```

---

Regarding `someObj`... do you want to have type safety when passing around and accessing that object?

**No:** consider annotating it with type `any`, `mixed`, or `Object` depending on what exactly you mean by "any".

**Yes:** you'll have to annotate it. You can write its type inline, but you can also define the type elsewhere (including in a different file), and reuse it in multiple places if needed. For example, like this:

```
type Thing = {
  foo: string;
  bar: number;
}
// ...
export function processThing(someObj: Thing): void {
```

If `someObj` is expected to be an instance of some ES6 class, you can also use that class as a type (see [docs](https://flowtype.org/docs/classes.html)).

---

As for `executeFunction`, you can specify that you want a function that accepts a `Thing` as its first argument, and returns nothing:

```
export function executeFunction(someFunc: (something: Thing) => void) {
```

Comment: Thanks! It's interesting that to specify a function returning a certain type, the syntax is `: string` in one case, but `=> string` in another. That's kind of confusing.

Comment: BTW, I believe `object` should be `Object`.

Comment: The `=>` is used to signify a function type. `:` is used for the return type when a function is already defined and you're annotating the type that will be returned. It makes sense when you think about it a bit.